# Python library that can read and write variable assignments inside Makefile files?

Tags: python, makefile

I am looking for a solution that would allow me to modify `Makefile` files from inside Python.

I don't need any special functionality, usually I need only to change variables like: `SOMETHING := value` but I would prefer to be able to use an existing library than implementing my own, buggy, parser.

Comment: What's the problem you're really trying to solve? Maybe we can suggest a nicer alternative to parsing and modifying source code.

Comment: Yeah, you don't really want to try programatically parsing Makefiles.  Simple templating as suggested by Timo is your best bet...or just pass in values in the environment or on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't heard of such Makefile oriented library for Python, but if you only need simple replacements such as `SOMETHING := [something_placeholder]`, then you can just load the template file, replace the placeholder with your value and write it back to disk and give it to `make`.

Or you could use a templating engine such as [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/), but this would be yet another dependency for your application.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to move away from Makefiles, if you want do things in Python.

Use `waf` or `scons` instead. They are build tools written in Python to replace Makefiles.
I'd rather use `waf` then `scons`, because it is faster and it works with the new `Python` versions (and some OS projects like `ardour` switched to it).

http://code.google.com/p/waf/

http://www.scons.org/

Here is a comparison of the two (and others like CMake, Ant):
http://code.google.com/p/waf/wiki/WafAndOtherBuildSystems#II._comparison_between_various_build_tools